Visual Studio Code crashes on Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS ERROR:process_memory_range.cc(75)]
I installed Visual Studio Code using snap package in Ubuntu Software manager. Now it is crashing on startup when trying to open it.
When using code --verbose to create a log in terminal, I get:
[0606/103410.331999:ERROR:process_memory_range.cc(75)] read out of range
[0606/103410.332035:ERROR:process_memory_range.cc(75)] read out of range
[0606/103410.332044:ERROR:process_memory_range.cc(75)] read out of range
[0606/103410.332074:ERROR:process_memory_range.cc(75)] read out of range
[0606/103410.332086:ERROR:process_memory_range.cc(75)] read out of range
[0606/103410.332094:ERROR:process_memory_range.cc(75)] read out of range

How can I fix the issue when using snap package for easy management and for self-containment?
I tried the harder approach by using the following script to manually install Visual Studio Code on my Ubuntu machine:
sudo snap remove code # Uninstall Visual Studio Code snap package

sudo apt-get install wget gpg
wget -qO- https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | gpg --dearmor > packages.microsoft.gpg
sudo install -D -o root -g root -m 644 packages.microsoft.gpg /etc/apt/keyrings/packages.microsoft.gpg
echo "deb [arch=amd64,arm64,armhf signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/packages.microsoft.gpg] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable main" |sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list > /dev/null
rm -f packages.microsoft.gpg

sudo apt install apt-transport-https
sudo apt update
sudo apt install code # Or 'code-insiders'

and consequently:
code --version

Output:
1.90.0
89de5a8d4d6205e5b11647eb6a74844ca23d2573
x64

It does not at least crash and opens up Visual Studio Code flawlessly. But is there an easier solution to fix the crashing issue?

Related (also Ubuntu): Visual Studio Code crashes with [...ERROR:process_memory_range.cc(75)] read out of range

What is the gist of it? Did Microsoft release a new version of Visual Studio Code that broke something? None of the answers explain why it happened.

cont' - It wouldn't be the first time (November 2021. Visual Studio Code version 1.62.2).

Command:
code --in-process-gpu .
Note:
The above command works for me. The option --in-process-gpu is the crux in the above command.
Reference:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/212494#issuecomment-2151807211
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/212494#issuecomment-2151817989

Chromium Switches For Further Study:
https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/

great, it works! But why doesn't just code . work as well ?

@MaciekWoźniak May be there is crash issue of vscode in renderer process. Therefore the option --in-process-gpu starts as thread in chromium rather than a process. To know how it is done see this source code: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/HEAD/content/gpu/in_process_gpu_thread.h

Remove the snap then
sudo snap install --revision 159 --classic code

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/204159#issuecomment-2151526680
OR

No need to reinstall or downgrade
code --in-process-gpu

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/212494#issuecomment-2152653486
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/212494#issuecomment-2151823774
May 2024 release of VSCode is breaking on Ubuntu 24.04, 23.10 

NOTE: It also crashes on Ubuntu 23.10. I haven't updated to 24.04 yet, but it crashes after update. :-P

You can run the previous running snap version until a fix to the problem comes in a new update. To do this, just run sudo snap revert code to execute it. If you want to pick another version, you can first list them snap list code and then select the revision sudo snap revert code --revision xx

start working, vs code won't open. stack overflow, 2 liner solution. back to work. Thank you! <3

Great, love this for future issues too

The easy way in this version (1.90) its sudo snap revert code. After that confirm that your current version is 1.89.1, with code -v

See https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/204159

uninstalled the snap version
Downloaded https://update.code.visualstudio.com/1.89.1/linux-deb-x64/stable
run sudo dpkg -i code_1.89.1-1715060508_amd64.deb


I uninstalled the snap version.
Download https://update.code.visualstudio.com/1.89.1/linux-deb-x64/stable or choose the latest stable version from official website of Visual Studio Code.
Then run sudo dpkg -i code_1.89.1-1715060508_amd64.deb and it is now
working again.
